# Rewrite Url to hide the information using lua regex

Tags: lua, fluent-bit

I am using lua plugin for fluentbit to hide my url.

```
original content
https://www.example.com/file/1234

marked content
https://www.example.com/xxxxxxx
```

What would be the proper regex to update the url string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to delete everything after the first `/` after `//`. The code below fits this description:

```
s="https://www.example.com/file/1234"
print((s:gsub("(.-//.-/)(.*)","%1xxxxxxx")))
```

Comment: if `s="https://www.example.com/file/1234 apple ball"`, this would remove everything, is there a way that I can only remove the url context?